# Hot to set the path for 'Help' in LiberOffice

Tags: libreoffice

I put the help files for LiberOffice on an external HD. When I click 'Help' in LiberOffice it goes to the WEB. I have tried the 'tools->options' but nothing there seems to be about the 'Help' files. I'm thinking about making a link,but I am not sure it that 1) will work, & 2) is the best way to fix this. 
I have LiberrOffice  4.3.7.2 and Win7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting aside the issue of why you'd want the help files on a separate HD in the first place, you can make a symbolic link ([tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) -- pay close attention to the "hard" symbolic link bit, as it's what you'll need and it's what I'm discussing here too).

Symbolic links are kind of shortcuts on steroids. Like a shortcut, symbolic links point to a totally different directory or file without actually containing that folder or file in the location where the link is located. UNLIKE a shortcut, however, a symbolic link is not just a little pointer (not a programming pointer!) to a location, nor are they actual files (yes, a Windows shortcut is actually a file! The extension is .INK, I think). Instead, a symbolic link is interpreted literally, as if that was the actual file/folder on the hard drive, so any given program should be able to read from a symbolic link just as if it were replaced with the contents it links to. You should be able to set up a symbolic link between the new help directory on your external hard drive and the directory that they used to be stored in. Be warned that sometimes this can be be finicky -- you need the exact name for the symbolic link completely correct, and you need it to link to the right directory. LibreOffice is going to treat that symbolic link as if it were the actual file folder, so make sure that if you were to navigate through that link to where it links to, the files/folders you see are EXACTLY the same as if you were on a normal setup with no linking.

Example: I symbolic linked a game save directory to my Dropbox folder, which the actual files residing in my dropbox folder. The game loaded the files just fine (no complaints whatsoever), and Dropbox kept itself busy keeping all my savegames up to date. I then completed the same procedure on another laptop, and voila, easy save-to-cloud ability!